# Gitlab CI Runner without routable IP

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to use Gitlab CI in my workflow, but because my project relies on licensed software, so I need it to run on my machine, which does not have a public, routable IP. My thought is that I can create a simple server on heroku to accept the webhooks and put the requests into a message queue (a redis DB, for instance), which my local machine can poll and actually run the CI job. It appears, however, that the entire Gitlab CI system is written assuming that the gitlab.com server can directly speak to the runner. Does anybody know of a proof of concept for proxying the CI build trigger through a webhook or making the gitlab-runner pull build jobs rather than accepting push events? I could roll my own runner if necessary that polls for build events and runs the commands I need, but it'd be really nice to use the existing, documented infrastructure/file format rather than reinventing the wheel. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had misinterpreted the documentation and this already works out of the box with the standard runner.

Comment: I believe the runner polls gitlab, not the other way around.